# How Can I Perform Awk Commands Only On Certain Fields

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have CSV columns that I'm working with:

```
info,example-string,super-example-string,otherinfo
```

I would like to get:

```
example-string super example string
```

Right now, I'm running the following command:

```
awk -F ',' '{print $3}' | sed "s/-//g"
```

But, then I have to `paste` the lines together to combine `$2` and `$3`.

Is there anyway to do something like this?

```
awk -F ',' '{print $2" "$3}' | sed "s/-//g"
```

Except, where the sed command is only performed on `$3` and `$2` stays in place? I'm just concerned later on if the lines don't match up, the data could be misaligned.

**Please note: I need to keep the pipe for the SED command.** I just used a simple example but I end up running a lot of commands after that as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk -F, '{gsub(/-/," ",$3); print $2,$3}' file
example-string super example string
```

#### How it works

1. `-F,`

   This tells awk to use a comma as the field separator.
2. `gsub(/-/," ",$3)`

   This replaces all `-` in field 3 with spaces.
3. `print $2,$3`

   This prints fields 2 and 3.

#### Examples using pipelines

```
$ echo 'info,example-string,super-example-string,otherinfo' | awk -F, '{gsub(/-/," ",$3); print $2,$3}'
example-string super example string
```

In a pipeline with sed:

```
$ echo 'info,example-string,super-example-string,otherinfo' | awk -F, '{gsub(/-/," ",$3); print $2,$3}' | sed 's/string/String/g'
example-String super example String
```

Comment: Oh, I think that would work. But, I kind of need to use the pipe because I run lots of commands. My example is a little too simple :-/

Comment: @DomainsFeatured OK.  I added an example showing how to use it in a pipeline.

Comment: I see what you're saying. And you are right. It's just that if you pipe the info into the sed command, it would remove the dash from `$2`

Comment: @DomainsFeatured Awk can do pretty much anything sed can do and, unlike sed, awk natively understands fields.  If you want to manipulate only one field, awk is the natural tool to use.

Comment: @DomainsFeatured Why do you think you would need to use `paste`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156396/discussion-between-domainsfeatured-and-john1024).

Answer (score 1):

Though best solution will be either use a single sed or use single awk. Since you have requested to use awk and sed solution so providing this. Also considering your actual data will be same as shown sample Input_file.

```
awk -F, '{print $2,$3}' Input_file | sed 's/\([^ ]*\)\([^-]*\)-\([^-]*\)-\([^-]*\)/\1 \2 \3 \4/'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
example-string  super example string
```